# time convert to miliseconds bug

Tags: javascript

I tried it yesterday but it worked out
I got this code

```
let str = document.querySelector("#content_value > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(11) > tbody > tr:nth-child(10) > td:nth-child(2) > span").textContent;
let timeParts = str.match(/\b(\d\d?):(\d\d?)(?::(\d\d?))?\b/) || [0,0,0];
console.log("Converted to array:", timeParts);
let [, h, m, s] = timeParts.map(str => +str || 0);
let cas = ((h * 60 + m) * 60 + s) * 1000;
console.log(cas);
```

code unfortunately does not convert seconds to milliseconds anyone would help?

[jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/bgoef2dn/2/)

is 3 time (text) and time

```
time
17:45
0:01:08
0:00:10
```

hour, minute, second and these three values need to be converted to milliseconds

this code works for hours and minutes but not seconds

[enter image description here][2]

[enter image description here][3]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDdYh.png this work
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FTuJ.png  second not working ( 18 second is 18000+1min 60000 (78000)) script give 1000

```
<span class="inactive"><span>Suroviny jsou k dispozici za <span class="">0:00:10</span></span><span
```

```js
function toms(str) {
  let timeParts = str.match(/\b(\d\d?):(\d\d?)(?::(\d\d?))?\b/) || [0,0,0,0];
  let [, h, m, s] = timeParts.map(str => +str || 0);
  let cas = ((h * 60 + m) * 60 + s) * 1000;
  return cas;
}

["1:02", "Suroviny jsou k dispozici za 0:01:35Suroviny jsou k dispozici.", "None"].forEach(str => console.log(str, toms(str)))
```

Comment: You're doing several things: 1) Find some text in the DOM 2) Parse text into time components 3) Convert to miliseconds. Please do some trouble-shooting (you can use the browser debugger or console.log if you're more comfortable with that) to find out which part isn't working.

Comment: You have an extra comma here. `let [, h, m, s] = timeParts.map(str => +str || 0);`. before you assign to `h`. Remove that comma and it works. `let [h, m, s] = timeParts.map(str => +str || 0);`

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bgoef2dn/2/)   3 time is @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: @Chin.Udara 0: this time (0:01:18)                "0:01"
1: "0"
2: "01" ( second is 3: undefined ) this is mi problem

Comment: @Chin.Udara The "extra comma" is there to throw away an unwanted value.

Comment: @IonSecred Show exactly what text string do and doesn't work. (add it to your question)

Comment: they just need to convert to milliseconds there is nothing else in it (this time they will use the refresh page) @some   0:00:10 this script not convert second to milisecond  ( h and m working S nod ( (0:01:18)  "0:01" 1: "0" 2: "01" aray ( 18 second undefined )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that your regex doesn't match, and you get your default `[0,0,0]` array, but when assigning to `h`, `m` and `s`, you throw away the first element, and you get `undefined` in s.

```js
function toms(str) {
  let timeParts = str.match(/\b(\d\d?):(\d\d?)(?::(\d\d?))?/) || [0,0,0,0];
  let [, h, m, s] = timeParts.map(str => +str || 0);
  let cas = ((h * 60 + m) * 60 + s) * 1000;
  return cas;
}

["1:02", "1:02:03", "Suroviny jsou k dispozici za 0:01:35Suroviny jsou k dispozici.", "None"].forEach(str => console.log(str, toms(str)))
```

Comment: can i ask for function code? Thank you @some

Comment: Change `[0,0,0]` to `[0,0,0,0]`, and look at what you get in h,m,s :) Since you have `timeParts.map(str => +str || 0)` the  `undefined` will be converted to 0.

Comment: 60000 and 18 second ignored same problem  <span class="inactive"><span>Suroviny jsou k dispozici za <span class="">0:00:10</span></span><span

Comment: If your string is "0:01" you will get `["0:01", "0", "01", undefined]` from the regex, but since you do `let [, h, m, s] = timeParts.map(str => +str || 0);` the `undefined` will be converted to 0.

Comment: i don't know it throws an error can i ask for the whole code modification? || [0,0,0,0]; same problem @some

Comment: `let timeParts = str.match(/\b(\d\d?):(\d\d?)(?::(\d\d?))?\b/) || [0,0,0,0];
console.log("Converted to array:", timeParts);
let [, h, m, s] = timeParts.map(str => +str || 0);
let cas = ((h * 60 + m) * 60 + s) * 1000;
console.log(cas);`

Comment: @IonSecred See example in my answer.

Comment: 0:01:35  this time im edited you code look same problem 35 second ignored

Comment: @IonSecred And now, when you have supplied the whole string, the error is clear: There is no space between the last digit and the S in the following text, and the seconds in the regex does not match.

Comment: can i ask for any code that would solve this? Thank you

Comment: @IonSecred Do you have control over the generated text? If so, the correct way is to add a space  between the number and the text. If you have no control over that, remove the last `\b` from the regex. (see updated answer)

Comment: @IonSecred You are welcome. I see that you have accepted my answer. Could you also vote up on it, please?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: @IonSecred Oh, sorry, I forgot that. I upvoted your question so now you have 15 :)